# Is it possible to access the parent of a Linq object?

Tags: c#, linq

In a situation where an `EntitySet` is being queried (in, say, a many-to-many relationship), is it possible to access the parent object?

e.g

```
Thing thing = db.Things.First();
Widget widget = thing.Widgets.First();
// Let's assume that Widgets can have many things as well
// (i.e. widget.Things is possible)
widget.ParentThing // would return the same instance of thing used above
```

Is that possible?

Comment: So when you tried it what happened?

Comment: No, not unless `Widget` has a reference to `thing` (which is logical and I assume you already ruled this out).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel In this exact situation? Nothing. `ParentThing` is a made up property for illustrative purposes.

Comment: If you mean: is it possible to have an association to 1 Entity besides a many-to-many association to many Entities of the same type, the answer is yes.

Comment: @GertArnold Do you have a link to an example (or something)?

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to access the parent object

With a many-to-many there really isn't a "parent" - there are multiple *related* objects.  A many-to-many is usually modeled with navigation properties:

```
public class Thing
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public virtual IEnumerable<Widget> Widgets {get; set;}
}

public class Widget
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public virtual IEnumerable<Thing> Things {get; set;}
}
```

If your model doesn't have such properties then an alternative is to go back to the context (or back to the db if you don't have the context anymore):

```
var relatedThings = db.Things
                      .Where(t => t.Widgets.Any(w => ID == widget.ID));
```

Comment: Yes, this much I have - `thing.Widgets` and `widget.Things` are both possible in my application - but if a `Thing` queries a `Widget` (e.g. `thing.Widgets.First();`) is there ANY way for the returned `Widget` to access the particular `Thing` that queried it?

Comment: OK I see now - not that I can think of - why do you need it?  There may be another way of getting what you need.

Comment: Right now I am passing the instance as an argument into the method call that needs it, and feels a little jicky. I was just hoping there was a way to clean it up a bit.